# SOAPFaultException when calling SOAP websevice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsimport, soapfault

I'm trying to call a webservice with a java client (wsimport) , when i make a call, i always get this Exception :

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.sendInvoice(Unknown Source)
    at com.audaxis.compiere.osg.ws.ClientEInvoice.sendEInvoice(ClientEInvoice.java:124)
    at com.audaxis.compiere.osg.ws.ClientEInvoice.callEInvoice(ClientEInvoice.java:203)
    at com.audaxis.compiere.osg.util.test.main(test.java:50)
10
```

So this is a test case of a webservice in `SoapUI` (works fine)

[image]

but, in `java` , i generated a client with `wsimport` , and tested the same case in SoapUI , and so i get the exception above.
Ps : the webservice was developed using C#, and the exception is a C# one.

1 - Client java :

This is the generated sendInvoice() service

```
 /**
     * 
     * @param sessionID
     * @param alias
     * @param invoice
     * @return
     *     returns java.lang.Boolean
     */
    @WebMethod(action = "http://tempuri.org/IPostBoxService/sendInvoice")
    @WebResult(name = "sendInvoiceResult", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "sendInvoice", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", className = "org.tempuri.SendInvoice")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "sendInvoiceResponse", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", className = "org.tempuri.SendInvoiceResponse")
    public Boolean sendInvoice(
        @WebParam(name = "invoice", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
        DocumentType invoice,
        @WebParam(name = "alias", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
        String alias,
        @WebParam(name = "sessionID", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
        String sessionID);
```

2 - Calling the service

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

        File         xml  = new File("/home/azb/Desktop/OSG2017000000368.xml");
        String      UUID = "f245c530-3387-40f3-8cc3-564892941764" ;

        //Compress XML to ZIP (required by the web service)
        String path = xml.getAbsoluteFile().toString();
        path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 4);
        File compressedXml = new File(path + ".zip");
        File encodedCompressedXML = new File(path + ".txt");
        zip(compressedXml, xml);

        //enconding compressedXml into Base64
        FileCodecBase64.encode(compressedXml.getAbsolutePath(), encodedCompressedXML.getAbsolutePath(), true); 

        GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.setTime(new java.util.Date());    
        XMLGregorianCalendar currentDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);

        Base64BinaryData data = new Base64BinaryData();
        data.setContentType(factory.createBase64BinaryDataContentType("Base64"));
        data.setValue(factory.createBase64BinaryDataValue(FileCodecBase64.getBase64EncodedData()));

        DocumentType ublInvoice  = new DocumentType();
        ublInvoice.setBinaryData(factory.createBase64BinaryData(data));
        ublInvoice.setFileName(factory.createElementTypeFileName(compressedXml.getAbsolutePath()));
        ublInvoice.setHash(factory.createElementTypeHash("DB94F3527130713C8E997FB5B453A177"));
        ublInvoice.setCurrentDate(currentDate);

        ClientEInvoice client = new ClientEInvoice("user", "psw", "https://test1.diyalogo.com.tr/Webservice/PostBoxService.svc", UUID); //in constuctor we instance the stub = new PostBoxService(new URL(url));    
        stub.getPostBoxServiceEndpoint().sendInvoice(ublInvoice, UUID, sessionID)
    }
```

does any one have a clue or a hint, on where should i start searching for the cause, i don't have access to the WebService, so i can't debug it.

Comment: What is the value of `EInvoice`?  where `stub` is declared? seem to me that parts of a code are missing....

Comment: sorry i make a mistake , its ublInvoice not EInvoice , it's corected now , thanks